# Zxing Android - Not scanning pdf417

Tags: android, zxing, pdf417

I am trying to scan a barcode in PDF417 format. I use zxing in my app and its not working. So I tried installing the barcodescanner+ from playstore and still no luck. In both cases it scans it as a UPC_E format and gets wrong data. Is there a way I can get around this

Comment: You should at least add the image of the barcode you are trying to scan.

Comment: I am not able to as its our client data. I could scan it with iOS and with some other pdf417 scanner from play store

Comment: Understandable, but without a reproducible source, only people within your organization are able to assist. You could try to log/instrument a custom copy of ZXing to see if you can find the issue. Or it could be as simple as not enough white space around the barcode. If you are trying to get outside help, then an image of  similar behaving barcode with dummy data is my only recommendation.

Comment: You could try to limit the barcodes it tries to detect and decode. when calling via intent you should be able to do[`intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PDF417_MODE");`](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java#L80).

Comment: you might want to us the [android-integration](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/android-integration) for easy intents and stuff. :)